# Error in access to python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm pretty sure that my error is a very small and stupid thing but I'm not capable to see it!! :(

I have a defined dictionary: self.names_to_nodes, and I want to access to one of its members with the key that I have.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
print "Result " + str(len( self.names_to_nodes))
if i in self.names_to_nodes:
    print "ESTA"
member = self.names_to_nodes.get(i)
ancestrosA.append(member.get_parent())
```

And I get this exit and this error:

Result 17

ESTA

```
143                     print "ESTA"
144                 member = self.names_to_nodes.get(i)
145                 ancestrosA.append(member.get_parent())
146                 i = member.get_parent()
147             ancestrosA.append(self.founder)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_parent'

How is this possible???

Thanks for your help! How get(i) is not finding the element if the key is in the dictionary?

BR,
Almu

Comment: Can you print `member` and see what you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.get` returns a value whether the key is in the dictionary or not. Example:

```
>>> x = {1:2}
>>> print(x.get(100))
None
```

Try using regular item access instead. Then your code will raise an exception if you try to get a nonexistent value. Example:

```
>>> x = {1:2}
>>> print(x[100])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 100
```

---

(Readers may ask, "but how could `i` not be a key in the dictionary? 'ESTA' was printed, and that only occurs when the membership test successfully passes". I'm assuming that this code is inside a `for` loop that changes the value of `i`, and the printed 'ESTA' is from the previous iteration, which ran without problems.)

Comment: You were right, my code was inside a while that changed the value of i, and the problem was that this value was not well assigned sometimes! I tried to simplify to ask the question and it was worse! Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the lookup inside the if statement if you want to make sure it exists before checking:

```
if i in self.names_to_nodes:
    print "ESTA"
    # only does a lookup if the key exists
    member = self.names_to_nodes[i]
    ancestrosA.append(member.get_parent())
```

You check if it exists but still check `i` outside the if so whether i exists or not you always do a lookup.